# To grab descriptor from a file

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
space='  ';
for dir in ./*/*;
do
    cd $dir
    for line in 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 29
    do
    tail -n $line OUTCAR | head -n 1 |awk '{print $NF}'$space >> descriptor
    echo '/t';
    done
    cd ../../
done
```

I have 116 directories where a document called OUTCAR is present.

Each OUTCAR is different from each other and the total number of lines in OUTCAR may vary but interestingly the quantity that I want to grab from each of them appears at 29 to 38 line number from bottom and at the end of each line.

I am successfully grabbing them, but I am not able to print them side by side in a new document called a descriptor.

Please look at the above code and suggest the required changes.

Comment: can u share a sample output...and expected output

Comment: 3.097
3.350
3.097
3.350
-0.210
-0.210
1.202
1.202
14.879

Comment: I want them to print in a single line seperated by a space or tab

Comment: @PrasunKeshri Welcome! msp9011 meant sample **input** and ouput. Please add these in the post, not in the comments.

Comment: You can abbreviate the for loop with `for line in {38..29}`.

Comment: @guillermochamorro That's if `30` was meant to be included (it isn't in the Q). Then maybe no loop - `tail -n 38 | head`

Comment: @guest you are right, i missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the new line with the delimiter you wish,

```
tail -n $line OUTCAR | head -n 1 |awk '{print $NF}'$space |tr '\n' '\t' >> descriptor`
```

- `tr '\n' '\t'` will replace the newline char with tab.

and remove `echo '/t';` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try - within the loop -

```
tail -n 38 | awk 'NR > 10 {printf ORS; exit} NR != 9 {printf "%s\t", $NF}'
```

If you can't live with the trailing `<TAB>` char, additional measures must be taken.